# Problemes with SD.remove ESP32

Tags: esp32

im using an esp32 wrover by freenove to take picture and store it in a sd card. this part is working well, but i want to remove all the pictures from the sd card with code so i wrote this in the setup

```c
//Lib Esp32
#include "SD.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "FS.h"                // SD Card ESP32
#include "SD_MMC.h"            // SD Card ESP32
#include "soc/soc.h"           // Disable brownour problems
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"  // Disable brownour problems
#include "driver/rtc_io.h"

#define EEPROM_SIZE 1


//Pins module Carte SD 
#define MOSI 14
#define MISO 32
#define CLK 13
#define SS 33


#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM   -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM    21
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM    26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM    27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM      35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM      34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM      39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM      36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM      19
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM      18
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       5
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM       4
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM   25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM    23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM    22

camera_config_t config;



File root;
int fileCountOnSD = 0; // for counting files


#define CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT



void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  
  // Initialising the UI will init the display too.
  

  //delay(200);

  Serial.println("//------------Initialisation-------------//");

  config_init();

  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA; // FRAMESIZE_ + QVGA|CIF|VGA|SVGA|XGA|SXGA|UXGA
    config.jpeg_quality = 5;
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } 
  else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 5;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }

  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  s->set_vflip(s, 1);        //1-Upside down, 0-No operation
  s->set_hmirror(s, 0);      //1-Reverse left and right, 0-No operation
  s->set_brightness(s, 1);   //up the blightness just a bit
  s->set_saturation(s, -1);  //lower the saturation


  //permet de définir les pins de la carte pour comm SPI 
  SPI.begin(CLK, MISO, MOSI, SS);

  //on vérifie si module SD présent
  if(!SD.begin(SS)){
    Serial.println("Card Mount Failed");
    //return;
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Card Mount Ok");
  }
  uint8_t cardType = SD.cardType();

  if(cardType == CARD_NONE){
    Serial.println("No SD card attached");
    //return;
  }

  root = SD.open("/");
  countingFiles(root, 0);

  // Now print the total files count
  Serial.println(F("fileCountOnSD: "));
  Serial.println(fileCountOnSD);

  for(int i=1;i<=fileCountOnSD;i++){
    String stringToDelete = "picture"+String(i)+".jpg";
    if(SD.exists(stringToDelete.c_str())){
      SD.remove(stringToDelete.c_str());
    }
    else{
      Serial.println("no file to remove");
    }
  }

  countingFiles(root, 0);
  Serial.println("after remove : ");
  Serial.println(fileCountOnSD);
  

  Serial.println("done!");


  Serial.println("//------------Fin Initialisation-------------//");

}


void loop() {

  //partie caméra
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;

  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();  
  if(!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    return;
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Camera capture ok");
    fileCountOnSD++;
    String path = "/picture" + String(fileCountOnSD) +".jpg";
    File file = SD.open(path.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
    if(!file){
      Serial.println("Failed to open file in writing mode");
    } 
    else {
    file.write(fb->buf, fb->len); // payload (image), payload length
    Serial.printf("Saved file to path: %s\n", path.c_str());
    }
    file.close();
  }

  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
  //tempo d'1s
  delay(1000);
}


//Fonction d'initialisation de la caméra 
void config_init() {
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  config.fb_count = 1;
}

void countingFiles(File dir, int numTabs) {
  while (true) {

    File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
    if (! entry) {
      // no more files
      break;
    }
    // for each file count it
    fileCountOnSD++;
  }
}
```

But it doesnt work. Here is the output :

```
22:55:10.433 -> //------------Initialisation-------------//
22:55:10.697 -> Card Mount Ok
22:55:17.256 -> fileCountOnSD: 
22:55:17.256 -> 8
22:55:17.256 -> no file to remove
22:55:17.256 -> no file to remove
22:55:17.256 -> no file to remove
22:55:17.256 -> no file to remove
22:55:17.256 -> no file to remove
22:55:17.256 -> no file to remove
22:55:17.256 -> no file to remove
22:55:17.256 -> no file to remove
22:55:17.300 -> after remove : 
22:55:17.300 -> 8
22:55:17.300 -> done!
```

I tried to look at the return of SD.exists and SD.remove, its always returning 0. This is why i have "no file to remove".

I dont know what i am doing wrong. I read the SD.remove and SD.exists documentation but i guess im missing something. I think the problem come from the string that i put in SD.exists and SD.remove but i dont find any solutions for now.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @superneiluj - welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it crash? Does it only remove some of the files? Does it remove none of them? What debugging have you done? Have you added a message to show how many files it's meant to be removing? Is it outputting the error message about "no file to remove"?

Comment: It's difficult to offer help with just a fragment of code, especially when we can't tell if the code is being called, or what `countingFiles()` does. That's why we ask that you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  that demonstrates the problem. In this case you could make a second program that doesn't contain the camera code and only has the code for removing files, run that, confirm the problem still exists, and share that program.

Comment: @romkey i edited, sorry for the inconvenience.